# create branch for general purpose?

Tags: git, workflow

I am using git workflow where `develop` branch is responsibe to being a single source of truth branch and as base/parent of feature branch. Usually I working in multiple feature branches and in paralel, the branches is `feat/auth`, `feat/crud-user`, `feat/crud-product`. All these branches are depending on main.scss which is responsible for general purposes such as set font size, update color palette, etc which is affect all the feature globally. So in my case do I have to create general branch such as 'global-design' or I just make main.scss changes in `develop` branch?

I don't need to doing revision of main.scss in every branches im working in

Comment: Why would you need to change your main.scss file in every branch? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Because the changes from main.scss affecting to all features

Comment: if you made a change in develop that you want in one of your feature branches, you can just pull the changes from develop into your branch. If you made the change on your feature branch, then it will be in develop as soon as you merge it.

Comment: so is it best practice to change main.scss in develop branch?

Comment: Change it where it is appropriate. If the change you make has  to do with one of your feat/* branches, commit the change in there. If it is part of some other work you do, make a commit on develop, or create another branch for the change and then merge it when it is appropriate. Your change will end up in develop either way and how you approach it is up to you.